# dataframe has a list of url's, beautiful soup breaks when making into string?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am using a dataframe with multiple urls from separate domains in it.

```
animal - url - trust
catdog - sdasd.html - .8
```

I want to take those urls and make them into a fourth and fifth column for for the text content of the url. Using beautiful soup like this,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify()[:1000])
```

I know will return html, which I am having trouble appending to my dataframe in a loop.

```
loop..
df.htmlblog = ...
```

Whats the best way to approach this?

### trying pd.read_html at the moment.

Comment: Do u wanna create a new column for each url? Or do u wanna append all urls to the same column?

Comment: append all urls to a new collumn - so like the data in the url is there. using pd.read_html at the moment.

Comment: Ok...So if there are 10 urls, do u wanna create 10 different columns? Or do u wanna append all 10 urls to the same column? Ur answer is not very clear.

Comment: And wht do u wanna append to the df? Do u wanna append the html code of the url to the df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help u:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

urls = ["https://www.google.com/","https://www.w3schools.com/"] #Sample urls

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    df[url] = [soup.prettify()]
df.index = ["Source code"]
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
                                      https://www.google.com/                         https://www.w3schools.com/
Source code  <!DOCTYPE html>\n<html itemscope="" itemtype="...  <!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en-US">\n <head>\...
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Does this do what u want? If yes, make sure that u accept this answer as the best answer. Thanks!